# Ошибка при установке pyTelegramBotAPI через termux: проблема с SSL сертификатом

Tags: python, telebot, установка

Делаю телеграм бота, для скачивания telegram api через termux ввел `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. Выдает ошибку

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pytelegrambotapi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pytelegrambotapi/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyTelegramBotAPI (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Компилятор pydroid 3, ибо сейчас на телефоне. Что делать?

Comment: откуда взялось "компилятор не видит модуль"? Ты вообще читал, что в ошибке написано?

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pytelegrambotapi/`
```

Это указывает на то, что не удалось установить соединение с хостом "pypi.org" на порту 443 (стандартный порт для HTTPS). Превышено максимальное количество попыток подключения.

```
Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")
```

А это сообщение говорит, что не удалось установить HTTPS-соединение из-за отсутствия доступного модуля SSL. Модуль SSL необходим для обеспечения шифрования и проверки подлинности при подключении через HTTPS.

Основная проблема, связана с отсутствием доступного модуля SSL в вашей системе, что мешает установке пакета из-за проблем с безопасным соединением.

Что бы решить эту проблему, нужно поставить библиотеки для работы с SSL в вашей системе.